# How do I add specific content from a collection view to another one?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have three elements in my UICollectionViewCell:

Two labels with name and price, and a quantity button.

I would like to add the name and the quantity with "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" to a specific collection view in the previous view controller and the price in another view controller. I may achieve this by using a segue to pass data to any view controller of my choice.

Also, at the same time, I want to keep track of the selections I make adding them to a table view below the collection view.

My guess is to create empty arrays for each item.. one for name, price and quantity.
I may be wrong.. and I tried to append my current selection and I know I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

To pass information to a previous viewController use a delegate protocol. Suppose `a` is your first viewController, and `b` is your second viewController.

- You can create a delegate protocol in `b` (here you specify a `func` you want to execute inside of `a`)
- Set `a` as the `delegate` for `b`
- write a function `yourDelegateFunction` in `a` , which your delegate protocol will call to update the viewController with your first collection.
- in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` call `delegate.yourDelegateFunction`

Here's a video with an easy guide for how this works:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BcBu30thIA

If you provide a sample of your code, and highlight where you experienced issues, I can provide a more precise solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll search more about protocols and delegate. I have taken several courses on swift online but apparently.. that is just not enough to achieve what I have in mind. It is quite overwhelming actually because I need to feed my collection view with certain objects in a Firebase database. When I achieve this (I hope soon), I will then move on to my solve my question, which is doing what you've suggested.